# Upgrade oralce jdbc driver in Weblogic 10

Tags: oracle, drivers, weblogic, jdbc

I found in Weblogic's documentation, 
"If you plan to use a different version any of the drivers installed with WebLogic Server, you can replace the driver file in WL_HOME\server\lib with an updated version of the file or add the new file to the front of your CLASSPATH."
But if I replace the JDBC jar, that would affect all the managed servers.  I just want to update the JDBC driver for one managed server that one particular application is deployed on.  How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a classpath parameter to the JVM args for the specific managed node.
To configure this go to the Remote Start tab for that managed node and add the new JDBC jar then the CLASSPATH variable for your OS in the Classpath parameter.  And restart the node.
To be more specific I would need to know you OS.